# How to check the key pressed in VB

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, hotkeys, registerhotkey

I am trying to make a program which needs you to select a hotkey, but you can only give a character from the code I've produced, where as I want to be able to set something like F9 as well. I have been through a few on this site and this is the closest to what I want. I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

This is what I've got so far.

```
Private Sub Configure_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyPress
    MsgBox("Your new hotkey is: " & e.KeyChar)
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [`KeyPress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx) event is not raised by non-character keys other than space and backspace; however, the non-character keys do raise the [`KeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`KeyUp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup(v=vs.110).aspx) events.

Comment: Cheers, I will try that.

Comment: You are welcome :) I also post a sample code for you. Hope you find it helpful.

Comment: If you mean string representation, you can use `.ToString()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`KeyPress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx) event is not raised by non-character keys other than space and backspace; however, the non-character keys do raise the [`KeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`KeyUp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup(v=vs.110).aspx) events.

Set `ReadOnly` property of your `TextBox1` to `true` and handle `keyDown` event:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyDown
    Me.TextBox1.Text = e.KeyData.ToString()
End Sub
```

This shows also the key combinations in te text box, for example if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> you will see `F9, Shift, Control` in text box.

You can use `KeyCode`, `Modifiers` and other properties of [`KeyEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)) to gain information about keys.

Comment: Cheers, this is exactly what I wanted! Thanks!